# Style isn't getting updated for collapsible div in jquery mobile 1.2.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Style of collapsible div is not getting updated. I am using the latest jquery-mobile 1.2.0 version . My code is as follows. Pls advice on what is missing

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="eventDetails">
<div data-role="content">
<div data-role="collapsible-set" class="collapsibleSetClass">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="b" class="collapsibleClass">
    </div>
</div>

</div><!-- /content -->
</div>
```

javascript used:

```
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
        $.mobile.collapsibleset.prototype.options.initSelector = ".collpasibleSetClass";
        initEvents();
    });

var initEvents = function(){
 $.mobile.changePage( "#eventDetails", { transition: "slide"} );
 var $description = $('.collapsibleClass');
 $description.html('');
 var $title = $('<h3/>').append(eventObj.eventTitle);
 var $eventDetails = $('<p/>').append(eventObj.eventDescription);
 $description.append($title).append($eventDetails);
 $('.collapsibleSetClass').collapsibleset("refresh");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to refresh a widget that hasn't initialized yet. You call `initEvents()` in the `mobileinit` event handler, which fires before anything has been initialized.

So most likely all you really need to do is remove the line that refreshes the collapsible widget(s) and jQuery Mobile will automatically initialize them:

```
var initEvents = function(){
 $.mobile.changePage( "#eventDetails", { transition: "slide"} );
 var $description = $('.collapsibleClass');
 $description.html('');
 var $title = $('<h3/>').append(eventObj.eventTitle);
 var $eventDetails = $('<p/>').append(eventObj.eventDescription);
 $description.append($title).append($eventDetails);
 //$('.collapsibleSetClass').collapsibleset("refresh");
}
```

Also note that you must include all your JS after the HTML of the page or the HTML element(s) you are selecting won't be available. I would recommend using `pageinit` for the first page rather than `mobileinit` for this reason.